# TLSv1.2 SSL Chat Java, SSLContext not available

Tags: java, eclipse, security, ssl

I have problems when run my SSL Chat program. I'm using Eclipse in Ubuntu. I try to run this code

```
 import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.net.ssl.*;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.cert.*;

public class SSLSocketClient {

    private static String host;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cipher = null;
        String portNo;
                int port = 0;
        boolean mykeystore = false;
        boolean chat = false;

        if (args.length == 5) {

            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

                if (args[i].equals("-host")) {
                    host = args[++i];
                    continue;
                }
                if (args[i].equals("-port")) {
                    portNo = args[++i];
                    port = Integer.parseInt(portNo);
                    continue;
                }
                if (args[i].equals("-cipher")) {
                    cipher = args[++i];
                    continue;
                }
                if (args[i].equals("-chat")) {
                    chat = true;
                    continue;
                }

                if (args[i].equals("-mykeystore")) {
                    mykeystore = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Please check again parameter!");
        }

        if (mykeystore) {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "mykeystore");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "kosuke");
        }

        SSLContext sc;
        try {
            sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sc.init(null, null, null);
            SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) sc.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket mysslsocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);

            if (cipher != null) {
                String[] cipherarray = { cipher };
                mysslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherarray);
            }

            SSLSession session= mysslsocket.getSession();

            X509Certificate cert;


            // cert = (X509Certificate) session.getPeerCertificates()[0];

        //  System.out.println(session.getPeerHost() + "has presented a certificate belonging to: ");
            //Principal p=cert.getSubjectDN();




            //if(chat) {
                //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                //BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( mysslsocket.getOutputStream()));

                //while(true) {
                    //String s= in.readLine();
                        //if (!s.equals("")) {
                            //out.write(s);
                            //out.write(" \r\n ");
                            //out.flush();
                            //if (s.equals(".")) break;
                    //  }
                //}
        //  }

            mysslsocket.startHandshake();
            mysslsocket.close();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When i try to run the argument in the terminal

```
java SSLSocketClient -host localhost -port 11111 -mykeystore
```

I got this responds:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.2 SSLContext not available

    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:142)
    at SSLSocketClient.main(SSLSocketClient.java:61)
```

I dont know what's wrong in my code. Ihave copied the keystore to the program source code but still doesn't work. Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Which version of the JRE are you using?

Comment: I don't know, i'm new in using Java in Eclipse, especially in Ubuntu. Is JRE the problem in here?

Comment: OK so i have created project in Java SE1.7 but still doesn't work. Is something wrong in my code or what?

Comment: Do you get the same error under Java 7? Are you using OpenJDK or the Oracle JDK?

Comment: I'm using the latest java 7 release, and i still get java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv2 SSLContext not available!

Answer (score 4):

`TLSv1.2` wasn't added to the default JCE provider until Java 7. See the [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext) and [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext) standard algorithm names references.

If you're stuck on Java 6 or earlier and absolutely need TLS 1.2, try the [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) provider.

Comment: So if i update the java to java 7 it will be no problem? And how do you update it into Java 7? I'm new into Java programming, especially in Ubuntu and Eclipse

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`.

Comment: You could also try `TLSv1.1`.